# LG C2 (TV as monitor) mouse/keyboard connectivity to pc?

Tags: mac, desktop-computer, external-display, tv

I've got a PC setup with LG C2 tv (which works great as a monitor for work/gaming) but i'd ideally like to use same keyboard/mouse with the mac when i connect it to this monitor.

Surprisingly a macbook air m2 is easily capable to handle 4k hdr at 60fps but the keyboad/mouse are annoying to plug/unplug via adapters to the mac. The way i have the TV setup its not very easy to plug things every day.

I was wondering if there is any way such that we can connect the mouse/keyboard to the tv directly and have the signal be forwarded to either pc or laptop depending on whats connected? Is it possible over HDMI?

Anyone else who did a similar setup? Any feedback is appreciated. I do not want to have a separate bluetooth apple specific key/mouse.

Comment: It is the PC/MAC you are controlling, not the TV so you can't connect the mouse/kb to the TV.  The only option is an additional piece of hardware to switch the keyboard and mouse between MAC and PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, it isn't possible over HDMI.**

Some monitors with direct USB-C connection allow this. Others with USB ports require an uplink from a standard USB port on the computer (in a nutshell those have an embedded USB hub that is completely independent from video connections).

TVs like the one mentioned in the question may have one or more USB ports that are to be used by the TV's software only, typically for mass storage devices.